# Using single precision floating points

Tags: visual-studio-2010, floating-point, precision, sse

I'd like to introduce some SSE commands to my C++ code. Such as this one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afh0zf75(v=VS.80).aspx

If I understand correctly, I have to set the floating point precision to single in order to use this kind of commands. Am I right?

If so, where do I do that? I work with visual studio 2010 and checked:

project->properties->c/c++->code generation->Floating point model

The options there are:

Precise (/fp:precise)

Strict (/fp:Strict )

Fast (/fp:Fast )

Fast=2 (/fp:Fast = 2)

Is the one before last option the one I need? If not, what should I do?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Would it be unreasonable to ask that you include the name of the SSE instruction here? The MSDN url provides no hint, and it's generally a bad idea to require people to visit external websites just to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you just use it. Include the header, and use the instruction.

Comment: you mean this: #include <xmmintrin.h> ?

Comment: Well, the MSDN page says `mmintrin.h`, but yeah, that should work too. If I recall correctly, `xmmintrin.h` includes `mmintrin.h`.